# Create default user at runtime in spring mvc using postContruct java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Need to create default user profile when my Web Application [Spring MVC] starts:

--using postConstruct

-- Create default user on start up

-- do not create same user in next run

-- Default user like admin with some other information like First Name, Last Name,DOB etc. and it should be stored in database.

Of-course I have  to follow proper mvc pattern like controller, model, service, repository, spring-configuration,spring-security configuration.

Please do not post code in `spring-boot` or `JSON`.
Any help will be highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Made it more readable and clear. Since no code is provided, It still is bad

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question have simple solution after lot of research I have concluded that using @PostConstruct anything can be create at initializing phase of the application.
Hare is What I have found:

```
    @Component
public class DbInit {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        User admin = new User("admin", "admin password");
        User normalUser = new User("user", "user password");
        userRepository.save(admin, normalUser);
    }
}
```

A reference from : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy
Thanks to this site a grate place to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class call SecurityUtil like below.

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class SecurityUtil {

    public static User getFirstTimeUser() {
        User defaultUser = new User();
        defaultUser.setActive(true);
        defaultUser.setUserId("admin");
        defaultUser.setFirstName("First Time");
        defaultUser.setLastName("Admin");
        defaultUser.setId(0L);
        defaultUser.setPassword(new Md5PasswordEncoder().encodePassword("admin", Constants.SALT));
        //Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setId(0L);
        role.setRoleName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        //roles.add(role);
        defaultUser.setRole(role);
        return defaultUser;
    }
```

Then call this method from Userservice class which is implemented from Spring's UserDetails.

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserFilter filter = new UserFilter();
        filter.setUserId(username);
        List<User> users = userDAO.find(filter);
        if (users != null && users.size() == 1) {
            return users.get(0);
        } else {
            if (userDAO.count() == 0) {
                return getFirstTimeUser();
            } else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username Not Found Exception");
            }
        }
    }
```